HTML filter form using submit buttons
I have a list of records that I want to be filterable.
I have a select for the 'year' parameter and a set of <button type="submit">s for the 'type' parameter.
Now, if I choose a year, the page reloads onchage, the <form> sets the GET parameter and php handles the query - as intended.
Next, I click on a type-button, the parameter gets added to the query string, the page reloads with the filtered results - everything as intended.
But it doesn't work the other way round: once I change the year again, it looses the type parameter.
I guess what I would want is something like a "checked" status on the buttons. A way to have one be preselected, similarly to how I set the selected option at the select.
Is there a HTML-only solution to my problem? I'm aware that it can be achieved easily using js, hiddenfields, clickhandlers, etc... but I'm looking for another solution.
Edit:
I wanted to give a MRE, but I don't know how to simulate the form actions inside the editor, sorry. If you want, you could save the snippet as .html file and run it locally.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <form>
        <button type="submit" name="type" value="A">A</button>
        <button type="submit" name="type" value="B">B</button>
        <select name="year" onchange="this.closest('form').submit()">
            <option value="2024">2024</option>
            <option value="2023">2023</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>




could you share the code you tries ?

Please provide us with a [mcve]

@mplungjan I added the code, but I don't believe the effect is reproducable inside the SO editor

Are you just looking to click a specific button in that onchange event, instead of submitting the form?

If you return the form from the server, then you can just set the selected on the select to what was passed

@mplungjan as stated, I already do this with the select, but would like the equivalent funtionality for the buttons

@David what you are suggesting could work in my current setup, but would break once I add another set of buttons with the same name

@LukasKroess: How about adding a hidden field for type (just before the buttons) which has the previously clicked value?

@David that's the solution I'm currently using, that I hoped to replace. It's not a huge problem, just a quirk, that, since the button already has a name attribute, I was hoping to find a solution that doesn't use JS as much. And before you ask: I could have both the button and the hiddenflied, but then I get the query string twice, like ?type=A&type=A
